# To hide the div on ajax call if I get result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

Here, I am getting result through ajax.
I want to hide div if I get the result from ajax. 
The below div that I want to hide if get the result through the ajax.

Here is my code,

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var dateselect=$("#dateselect").val();
    var userselect = $("#employee").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "<?php base_url() ?>manage_attendance/listing",
        data:'dateselect='+dateselect+'&userselect='+userselect,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {                        
            $('.clkin_time').html(data.result);
                   if(data.clkout_result != "0000-00-00 00:00:00") {
                       $('.clkout_time').html(data.clkout_result);
                         //document.getElementById('selecttime').style.display = "hidden";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('.clkout_time').html("---");
                    }                        
         }
    });
});
```

My html part is,

```
<div id="selecttime">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Select Time</label>
    <div class="input-group date col-lg-2" id="datetimepicker5" style="display:inline-flex;">
        <select id="time_date1" class="form_control" name="time_date1">
            <?php 
                 for($i=00;$i<=23;$i++)
                 {
                     echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
                 }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select id="time_date2" class="form_control" name="time_date2">
            <?php 
                 for($i=00;$i<=59;$i++)
                 {
                      echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
                 }
             ?>
        </select>
        <select id="time_date3" class="form_control" name="time_date3">
             <?php 
                 for($i=00;$i<=59;$i++)
                 {
                      echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
                 }
             ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, I want to hide this div if I get the result as above.
How can we do this?

Comment: use `$("#selecttime").hide()`

Comment: This works.. Thanks Parth...!!

Comment: callback success is deprecated, use instead done()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
//this will do display:none in style
$("#selecttime").hide();
```

and for show use

```
//this will do remove  display:none from style
$("#selecttime").show();
```

Please check [Document](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 5):

Try like following. Use `display` attribute value `none` instead of  `hidden`.

```
document.getElementById('selecttime').style.display = "none";
```

Or you can use `jquery` `hide()` function like following.

```
$("#selecttime").hide();
```